# What is meaning of ({}) while writing a function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, components

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const Todo = ( {onClick, completed, text} ) =>(
    <li 
    onClick ={onClick}
    style = {{
        textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'
    }}
    >
    { text }
    </li>
)

Todo.propTypes = {
    onClick:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    completed:PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    text:PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default Todo
```

1)I have come across the code for Todo in OfficalDocumention

2) I was confused with  `const Todo = ( {onClick, completed, text}` ) these part

3) Are we using destructing(es6 syntax)  or we passing object type using json short Hand Syntax

Comment: it does destructuring of an object passed as a function parameter to put its relevant properties into respective variable parameters and skip all the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional component is a function that receives one parameter: `props`. Since props is always an object, you can choose to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it's properties into their own variables using this syntax.

This is not limited to functional components though. Consider the following function:

```js
cont myObj = {
  val: 'foo',
  other: 'bar'
}

function myFunction({ val, other }) => {
  return val + other;
}

myFunction(myObj); // foobar
```

Its a way to more explicitly declare a function's parameter requirements when using an object as an argument, and it also assigns them to variables so that you don't have to reference each one as `myObj.val` or `myObj.other`.

So the functional component equivalent would be:

```js
<MyComponent val="foo" other="bar" />

// Underneath react still calls our functional component like this
// where props is an object containing val and other
MyComponent(props) 

const MyComponent = ({val, other}) => {...}
```

Comment: Thanks 
For the explanation